# issue with importing api to jupyter

Tags: python, api

```py
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(“farasa-api.qcri.org”) payload = “{\”text\”: \”هذا مثال بسيط\”}”

headers = { ‘content-type’: “application/json”, ‘cache-control’: “no-cache”, }

conn.request(“POST”, “/msa/webapi/lemma”, payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()

data = res.read()

print(data.decode(“utf-8”))
```

the result is showing as this

```sh
File "<ipython-input-61-b6148c5a04bb>", line 3
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(“farasa-api.qcri.org”) payload = “{\”text\”: \”هذا مثال بسيط\”}”
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

can anyone help? I need to import this api.

Answer (score 2):

Payload have to be under your conn and your double quote are "different" than normal :

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("farasa-api.qcri.org") 

payload = "{\"text\": \"هذا مثال بسيط\"}"

headers = { 'content-type': "application/json", 'cache-control': "no-cache", }

conn.request("POST", "/msa/webapi/lemma", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()

data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```